# What does basic_string<char> means in typedef basic_string<char> string;

Tags: c++

Hello does anyone know what `basic_string<char>` in `typedef basic_string<char> string;` stands for? What does `basic_string<char>` mean?

Comment: Within namespace `std`, in standard header `<string>` there is a templated class named `basic_string`, and `string` is a specialisation of that template using the `char` type.  So `std::string` is a specialisation of `std::basic_string` that works on `char` types, representing a collection of `char`.   Similarly, a wide string (a string represented as a set of wide characters, named `wchar_t` ) is also a specialisation of `std::basic_string` named `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`.  For more information, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basic type for creating different strings with different types that are representing a symbol. For example, in `typedef std::basic_string<wchar_t> std::wstring;` they make analogical string but with `wchar_t` type.

Comment: Cool thx why <> brackets are used?

Comment: It's the syntax for implementing templated classes and function or, in this case, instantiating the template for a particular type.   Any basic C++ text will have a section devoted to templates.

Comment: Thx very much! : )